# Why the destructor gets called before doing the copy?

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
class Mesh
{
public:
    Mesh();
    Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<GLuint> indices);
    ~Mesh();
    void draw(Shader& shader);

private:
    std::vector<Vertex> mVertices;
    std::vector<GLuint> mIndices;
    GLuint mVBO;
    GLuint mEBO;
};

Mesh::Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<GLuint> indices)
{   
    mIndices = indices;
    glGenBuffers(1, &mEBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mEBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &mIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    mVertices = vertices;
    glGenBuffers(1, &mVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &mVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    computeBoundingBox();
}

Mesh::~Mesh()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &mVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &mEBO);
}

void Mesh::draw(Shader& shader)
{   
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mEBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO);

    GLuint vpos = glGetAttribLocation(shader.program(), "vPosition");
    GLuint vnor = glGetAttribLocation(shader.program(), "vNormal");

    glVertexAttribPointer(vpos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vnor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)sizeof(Vector));

    shader.bind();
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vpos);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vnor);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mIndices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    shader.unbind();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void loadSquare(Mesh& mesh)
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.f), Vector(1.f, 0.f, 0.f)));
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.f), Vector(0.f, 1.f, 0.f)));
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f), Vector(0.f, 0.f, 1.f)));
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f), Vector(1.f, 0.f, 1.f)));

    std::vector<GLuint> indices;
    indices.push_back(0);
    indices.push_back(1);
    indices.push_back(2);
    indices.push_back(0);
    indices.push_back(2);
    indices.push_back(3);

    mesh = Mesh(vertices, indices);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Create opengl context and window
    initOGL();

    // Create shaders
    Shader shader("render.vglsl", "render.fglsl");

    Mesh mesh;
    loadSquare(mesh);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mesh.draw(shader);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to run it it just displays a gray image on the window it creates.

After tracking the application with the debugger, when it hits the line `mesh = Mesh(vertices, indices)` it creates the buffers for OpenGL and copy the vertices and indices std::vectors to the variable `mesh` that was passed as parameter.
However, it also calls the destructor of the object created by `Mesh(vertices,indices)` which in turn invalidate the buffers in the OpenGL context, so when then application reaches `mesh.draw(shader)` the buffers mesh points to are not valid anymore.

Does the move-constructor can help me solve my problem, i.e. avoid the call to the destructor of `Mesh(vertices,indices)`? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `mesh = Mesh(vertices, indices);` -- Read up on the [Rule of 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and please pass things like this by (const) reference: `std::vector<Vertex> vertices`

Comment: Note: make your parameters to `Mesh::Mesh(...)` references. You're doing a whole lot of unnecessary copying.

Comment: `Surprisingly, if I comment the code of the destructor of the mesh it works.`  -- It is no surprise.  Also by commenting out the destructor, you've refused to run code that has to run to clean up the resources.  I wouldn't call that "working".

Comment: That's not the right way to copy GL-managed resources. The copy constructor will copy the GL names (generated with `glGen* (...)`), but those aren't valid after the original object is destroyed.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman yes I think the problem is that, even if the vbo and ebo have the value from the tempoary object created through `Mesh(vertices,indices)` when the destructor was called, those values are not valid anymore in OpenGL's context, i.e. nothing to render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your source, your are doing the bind to vectors that are immediately destroyed.

Essentially, in your loadSquare function you are creating a mesh and binding it when you write *Mesh(vertices, indices);* on the right side of the assignment in the last line of loadSquare.

```
mesh = Mesh(vertices, indices);
```

Think that line like this:

```
  ...
  Mesh m1(vertices, indices);  // a 
  mesh= m1;                    // b
  // m1 gets destroyed here.
}
```

Line (a) creates and binds the mesh.

When you assign it to mesh in line b, mesh.mVertices and mesh.mIndices will get copies of the vectors and mVBO and mEBO will get copies of the bound values.

Think of that line (b) as writing

```
mesh.mVertices= m1.mVertices;  // mesh gets a new vector with the same values
mesh.mIndices= m1.mIndices;    // mesh gets a new vector with the same values
mesh.mVBO= m1.mVBO;
mesh.mEBO= m1.mEBO;
```

At the end of loadSquare() m1 will be destroyed (destructor called).

In your calling function you will end up with mesh containing mVBO and mEBO members bound to the vectors that were destroyed.  It contains its own vectors, these have the same values, but these are copies in different memory locations that were never bound.

There are various ways to solve this, e.g. returning the square mesh through pointer.  Or writing an assignment operator (google for shallow copy).

But my suggestion would be to create a an empty constructor and an additional fillMesh function like your current cotstructor.

```
Mesh::Mesh(void);            // set mVBO and mEBO to zero.
void Mesh::fillMesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<GLuint> indices);  // same code as your current constructor.
```

Then rewrite your loadSquare function like this:

```
void loadSquare(Mesh& mesh)
{
 std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
 vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.f), Vector(1.f, 0.f, 0.f)));
 vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.f), Vector(0.f, 1.f, 0.f)));
 vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f), Vector(0.f, 0.f, 1.f)));
 vertices.push_back(Vertex(Vector(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f), Vector(1.f, 0.f, 1.f)));

 std::vector<GLuint> indices;
 indices.push_back(0);
 indices.push_back(1);
 indices.push_back(2);
 indices.push_back(0);
 indices.push_back(2);
 indices.push_back(3);

 mesh.fillMesh(vertices, indices);
}
```

Thus the loadSquare will create the vertices and indices and set them into the mesh from the calling function and bind them.

Further notes (for a clean solution):

- The destructor should probably also unbind the vector and indices from
  GL.
- The fillMesh function should probably check if the mesh is
  already bound and unbinds the old vectors before setting and binding
  the new ones (in case you are calling fillMesh again on an active mesh).
- You should probably still write an assignment operator that calls fillMesh: 
  Mesh::operator=(const Mesh &other);  // google shallow copy

Comment: There's also a double-free situation caused by allowing the compiler to generate an implicit copy constructor. `glDelete* (...)` frees the original name generated by `glGen* (...)`, whenever the original or its copied object is destroyed it will cause problems with the remaining one. Reference counting is necessary to solve that sort of sharing without completely unpredictable results, but it is probably better to explicitly forbid copy construction if you're going to hold on to references to GL-managed names.

Answer (score 1):

The Mesh constructor gets called when you instantiate Mesh(vestices, indices). This is just a temporary object instance. The code is then calling the assignment operator to copy the temporary object instance into the mesh variable. Since you haven't defined operator= [given the code provided], it does a default assignment behavior. Once that assignment is completed the ~Mesh destructor gets called.

Comment: Yes, which in turn, delete any opengl buffers created for this temporary object. Moreover, even if mesh copy the values from this temporary object, the buffers in the opengl context were deleted, i.e. nothing will be rendered. I guess I need to avoid the destructor somehow and I was thinking about a good use of the move constructor, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You violated [rule of three (rule of five)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and of course you get issue after doing assignment. On this line:

```
mesh = Mesh(vertices, indices);
```

you create a temporary object that destroyed immediately after the statement. So properly implement or prohibit copy ctor and copy assignment operator to resolve the issue. You may want to implement move ctor and move assignment operator as well, especially if you prohibit copying.